# Rotation and Offset Kinetic js

Tags: javascript, rotation, kineticjs, offset

im struggling with a problem for days

if i drag the circle near the arrow haead and resize my whole arrow the rotation is not going to be around the right center when

i press the rotate button

any thoughts?

the rotation should always be centered around the green knob

UPdate: http://jsfiddle.net/d9nAq/2/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var anchor1 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    radius: 10,
    fill: "blue",
    draggable: true
});
anchor1.on("dragmove", function () {
    connector.repoint();
});
layer.add(anchor1);

var anchor2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 200,
    y: 75,
    radius: 10,
    fill: "green",
    draggable: true
});
anchor2.on("dragmove", function () {
    connector.repoint();
});
layer.add(anchor2);

var connector = new Kinetic.Polygon({
    points: [],
    strokeWidth: 1,
    fill: "red",
});
connector.arrowHeight = 12;
connector.arrowWidth = 16;
connector.anchorRadius = 5;
connector.repoint = function () {
    var x1 = anchor1.getX();
    var y1 = anchor1.getY();
    var r1 = anchor2.getRadius();
    var r2 = anchor2.getRadius();
    var dx = anchor2.getX() - x1;
    var dy = anchor2.getY() - y1;
    var lineLength = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) - r2 - this.arrowWidth;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    var points = [];
    points.push(r1, 0);
    points.push(lineLength, 0);
    points.push(lineLength, -this.arrowHeight / 2);
    points.push(lineLength + this.arrowWidth, 0);
    points.push(lineLength, this.arrowHeight / 2);
    points.push(lineLength, 0);
    points.push(r1, 0);
    this.setPoints(points);
    this.setPosition(x1, y1);
    this.setRotation(angle);
    layer.draw();
}
layer.add(connector);
connector.repoint();

document.getElementById('P10005_ROTATE_RIGHT').addEventListener('click', function() {


          var arrow = layer;

        var deg = arrow.getRotationDeg();


        arrow.setRotationDeg(deg+15);


      // arrow.setPosition([arrowx-xoff,arrowy-yoff]);
       console.log(arrow.getPosition());
        console.log(arrow.getOffset());


    layer.draw();

        }, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects in Kinetic rotate around their offset point.

So, if you want everything to rotate around anchor2 then all the "satellite" objects must have their offsets pointed to the centerpoint of anchor2.

If you move either anchor2 or any satellite, then each satellite offset must be reset to point to anchor2's centerpoint.

Problem:

A Kinetic object's position is automatically linked to it's offset point.  If you change the offset point the object will automatically be repositioned visually on the stage.

To point any object's offset at anchor2 you need to know where that object is on the stage. Unfortunately, Kinetic's anyObject.getAbsolutePosition does not return the offset+transformed position of that object.

Without the ability to know an objects dragged+rotated position there is no solution within the Kinetic framework itself.

That's why you've been having days worth of headaches searching for a solution inside Kinetic...there isn't one :-(

**The theoretical solution**

You can use trigonometry to calculate each satellite's rotated position relative to anchor2.  Armed with the true rotated position you can set the satellite's offset+position and make your project work.

Comment: thank you!!!! i figured out how this will work in the fiddle, but waht should i do if the layer of the group has a pre set position and the objects already have offsets any clue?

Comment: You're welcome!  If you put all your objects on a group (or layer) then that group's offset must point to anchor2's centerpoint to allow everything to rotate around anchor2. When you offset the group all objects on the group will maintain their **offsets relative to each other**. But since the group's offset has been changed, the group's position must be altered accordingly or it will visually "jump" to a different place on the stage.  The adjustment is half-width-and-height.  But for a **rotated group** you must use trigonometry to calc the new position since Kinetic doesn't provide a way.